# React: window event subscription

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting into React and trying to create some kind of keyboard trainer app.

I want to add a `keypress` event listener to the window object to get the letters, and then update the state I created with `useState()` hook.

So I add the event listener inside `useEffect` hook. with the custom handler. But the `setPhrase` function doesn't seem to work well in this case.

**Expected result**:
After each correct key press the `phrase.written` to add this key as text, `phrase.left` to substring by this letter;

**Actual result**:
State is renewed every time, so the state doesn't update after `setPhrase` call

**The code:**

```
export default () => {
  const [initialPhrase] = useState("Test Phrase");
  const [phrase, setPhrase] = useState({
    left: initialPhrase,
    written: "",
  });

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    const requiredLetter = phrase.left.charAt(0);

    if (requiredLetter === event.key) {
      setPhrase({
        written: phrase.written + event.key,
        left: phrase.left.substring(1, phrase.left.length),
      });
    }
    console.debug(phrase, requiredLetter, event.key, phrase);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="phrase">
        <span className="phrase--part phrase--part__written">
          {phrase.written}
        </span>
        <span className="phrase--part phrase--part__left">{phrase.left}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Playground:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qgbjaf?file=src/index.js

*Note: if you place this handler to any element inside component, it is going to work just as expected*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the handleKeyPress Method is not updated after the phrase state updated. Therefore, you need to add the handleKeyPress method to the useEffect dependency. Now after each phrase state update, the method gets the correct state of phrases

Stackblitz fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bx5qp7?file=src/index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const KeyboardTrainer = () => {
  const [initialPhrase] = useState('Test Phrase');
  const [phrase, setPhrase] = useState({
    left: initialPhrase,
    written: '',
  });

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
      const requiredLetter = phrase.left.charAt(0);
      if (requiredLetter === event.key) {
        setPhrase({
          written: phrase.written + event.key,
          left: phrase.left.substring(1, phrase.left.length),
        });
      }
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
      handleKeyPress(e);
    });
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keypress", handleKeyPress);
  }, [handleKeyPress]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="phrase">
        <span className="phrase--part phrase--part__written">
          {phrase.written}
        </span>
        <span className="phrase--part phrase--part__left">{phrase.left} 
        </span> 
      </p>
    </div>
     )};

ReactDOM.render(<KeyboardTrainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Wow, this one seems amazing, I also tried @ahmetkilinc 's answer, and it also worked, but seems much more bulky

Comment: Thanks, using a ref is a bit overkill. You definetly could use that,but there are more elegant ways :). What you could also do is pass the phrases state object to the handleKeyPress method as a parameter. Then you need to add phrases to the useEffect dependency. But this depends on your likes. Either way its gonna work with adding the right dependency

Answer (score 1):

in your event handler method you cant reach the updated state, because state variables don't update itself inside an EventListener. just use useRef like this:

```
const phraseRef = useRef({
    left: initialPhrase,
    written: '',
  })

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    const requiredLetter = phraseRef.current.left.charAt(0);

    if (requiredLetter === event.key) {
      setPhrase({
        written: phraseRef.current.written + event.key,
        left: phraseRef.current.left.substring(1, phraseRef.current.left.length),
      });
    
      phraseRef.current = {
        written: phraseRef.current.written + event.key,
        left: phraseRef.current.left.substring(1, phrase.left.length),
      }
    }
    console.debug(phrase, requiredLetter, event.key, phrase);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct explaining why this one doesn't work - your variant really works well, except seems too bulky